# Find and Replace using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to use Notepad++ to do some find and replace as I'm dealing with up to few thousand of lines of data.

The below is the example of the data structure that i am dealing with.

```
A = Can be any Aplabet
X = Can be any Number 0-9
RX = Number that I want to replace with another value.

AAAAA X.XXXXXX X.XXXXX X X X X X XX:XX:XX:XX.XXX XXX RXRXRXRXRXRX XXXXXX XXXXXX

Actual Example

werwer 2.178924  1.17892  1 1 1 1 1   12:14:44:59.123  123  0123123  123345  123123
gret   2.178975  1.15731  1 1 1 1 1   12:14:44:59.123  123  0123     123345  123123
sdfwe  2.123245  1.15171  1 1 1 1 1   12:14:44:59.123  123  0555312  123345  123123
```

Is there a shortcut I can use?

Comment: http://superuser.com/ would be a better place for such questions.

Comment: I am no fan of Regex but I am pretty sure some one will definitely come up with a RegEx solution :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

refer to https://superuser.com/questions/214079/find-and-replace-using-notepad

whitequark solution

Answer (score 1):

N++ is not the tool for the job as it has very limited regexp capabilities. In a decent editor, you could replace

```
((?:[a-zA-Z0-9:\.]+\s+){10})\d+(.*)
```

with

```
\1your_text\2
```

but notepad++ regex syntax supports neither `(?:)` nor `{10}`.

There are lots of regex tools out there, choose whichever.

P.S. I also tried repeating the first pattern ten times to emulate `{10}`, it still did not work strangely.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the sort of job that is perfect for awk.

```
awk '{print "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 NUMBERS I'\''M CHANGING $11 $12"}' < file.txt > newfile.txt
```

You can also try vim's Block Highlighting and Insert/Change functionality.  I don't know if notepad++ has anything similar to it.

Answer (score -1):

press ctrl+F and then go to Replace tab.